# Oracle SQL - Insert Statement with Where Clause

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, sql-insert, where-clause

I'm trying to insert data into a particular column in a particular line in the table and I am sure I am doing something wrong since this is my first doing an Insert statement with Where:

```
insert INTO mekka_h_o_a_fees
  columns(money_handed_to_commity),
  Where Month_Year = July
  VALUES(Yes)
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want `update`, not `insert`. The syntax is:

```
update mekka_h_o_a_fees
set money_handed_to_commity = 'Yes'
where month_year = 'July'
```

This sets column `money_handed_to_commity` to `'Yes'` on the row(s) where column `month_year` has value `'July'`.

Comment: True, the Row is already there I only need to update an empty cell

Comment: what if I wanna update multiple Months ?  I tried this and it didnt work

Comment: update mekka_h_o_a_fees
set money_handed_to_commity = 'Yes' 
Where month_year = 'August''SEPT';

Comment: @AnouarSeljouki: `where month_year in ('August', 'Sept')`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to insert a new row based on another row in a different table then you can use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... WHERE ...` (and you need single quotes around the string literal values):

```sql
INSERT INTO mekka_h_o_a_fees (money_handed_to_commity)
SELECT 'Yes'
FROM   some_table
WHERE  Month_Year = 'July';
```

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO Student (ID, First_Name, Last_Name)
SELECT ID, F_Name, L_Name From StudentClass10
WHERE ID = 101 And F_Name = 'Roshan';
```

Roshan Kumar Men.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).